# Javascript Array Losing an Element At Random

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jstree

I have a very strange issue that I am running into.  I am using jsTree from JQueryUI on one of my sites, and I have different implementations of it used in different .js files.  One of them seems to work, which is very confusing as it uses almost identical code (only the variable names are different) to the implementation that is broken.  The problem comes from the contextmenu function.  The code I am using is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(typeof dryerList == 'undefined' || dryerList.length == 0) {
        var dryerList = [];
        $.ajax({
            url:'../TrackingApp/getGrainBins.php?t=234.23423452353',
            async: false,
            success: function(text) {
                try {
                    dryerList = $.parseJSON(text);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert('ERROR: ' + e);
                }

                if(dryerList.length == 0) {
                    alert('ERROR: No fleet data received.')
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $("#dryerListTree").jstree({
        plugins : ['json_data', 'ui', 'themes', 'contextmenu'],
        contextmenu: {items: customBinMenu},
        json_data : { data: binNodes }
    });

    $('#dryerListTree').bind("dblclick.jstree", function (event) {
        var node = $(event.target).closest("li");
        var id = node[0].id;

        for(i=0; i < dryerList.length; i++) {
            if(id == dryerList[i].id) {
                centerMap(dryerList[i].y, dryerList[i].x);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});


function customBinMenu(node) {
    if ($(node).hasClass("folder")) {
        return;
    }

    var items = {
        centerItem: {
            label: "Locate",
            action: function () {
                // Centers map on selected bin
                var id = node[0].id;

                for(i=0; i < dryerList.length; i++) {
                    if(id == dryerList[i].id) {
                        centerMap(dryerList[i].y, dryerList[i].x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        dashboardItem: {
            label: "Dashboard",
            action: function () {
                // Opens dryer info window over map
                var id = node[0].id;
                var dryerIndex = -1;

                for(i=0; i < dryerList.length; i++) {
                    if(id == dryerList[i].id) {
                        dryerIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

return items;
}
```

The strange bit is, the double-click handler works just fine.  When I get to the customBinMenu() function, the dryerList array is there, and dryerList[0] contains 4 of the 5 values that it should- but somehow the 'id' element has been dropped from that object.  I have been looking at this for quite some time, and I can't figure out how it can drop a single element from the object without losing any other data, especially when identical code is working for a similar list.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using the global variable "i" in three places. You really need to very careful in JavaScript to declare your local variables with `var`.

Comment: I'm using it in multiple places, but only sequentially- the variable is reset each time I use it, and not used again until it has been reset.

Comment: I agree that it's probably not the issue, but it's a risky unnecessary practice nevertheless.

Comment: So are you saying that I should use unique iterators for every for loop in my code?

Comment: if you know what you are doing, there is no reason to my knowledge NOT to reuse i as to count your iterations. Just don't nest them! However you also might want to seriously optimize your loops. Don't get dryerList.length on every iteration!!! Also do reverse loops: i=dryerList.length; while(i--){//actions} where-ever possible!

Comment: I think I may have missed something- did I nest them somewhere in this code?  I didn't see it, but I tend to miss the simplest things and have huge problems because of it...

Comment: @GitaarLAB Can you give some info on why reverse loops are better?  Is it easier to traverse memory from the end?  Or is it something about the way the elements are set up in memory?

Comment: Well using an implicitly global variable like that is erroneous in strict mode.

Comment: simple: evaluateTrueFalse(getValue compared to getOtherValue). Those are quite some operations... where-as while will stop if: while(0). So.. if i get's down to zero... it's while(0). Just one command :) There are also some jsperfs to this, ill find one.

Comment: Also, it might help (since it is actually pretty decent code and coding-style) if you'd give us a js-fiddle test-case to find this 'bug'.

Comment: @Pointy, that is actually a good catch. Indeed. always declare your vars inside your functions!!! Due to scoping! But it is probably not what is going wrong, he is still setting global i to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I read in your question: *'and dryerList[0] contains 4 of the 5 values that it should- but somehow the 'id' element has been dropped from that object'*
So by *'element'* and *'value'* I assume you mean 'attribute': the node's 'id'-attribute to be precise ??

I see in your code: `var id = node[0].id;`

That should be: `var id = node[0].getAttribute("id");`

Good luck!

**UPDATE 1:**
Ok, if (as per your comment) `var id = node[0].id;` (getting id from node[0]) is ok, then `if(id == dryerList[i].id)` looks wrong, since you just (re-)defined id to be the value of node[0]'s id.
Actually I would not use 'id' as a var-name (in this case).

So what if you did: `var idc = node[0].getAttribute("id");`
and then: `if(idc === dryerList[i].getAttribute("id"))`

**UPDATE 5:** You still have some errors by the way:

- You forgot a semi-colon to close the alert in:
  `if(dryerList.length == 0) {
      alert('ERROR: No fleet data received.')
   }`
- You should use '===' to compare with '0' on line 2 and 14
- naturally in real life you would define function customBinMenu(node) before it was used in your document.ready function.
  Fixed by swapping code order.
- The same goes for this document.ready function where you used var dryerList before it was defined.
  Fixed by: `var dryerList = dryerList || []; if(dryerList.length === 0){//ajax & json code}`

Could you please **confirm** if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhvbs/3/), which *is now valid javascript*, represents your intended *baseline-code* that still results in your problem of the 'id'-attribute being 'undefined' in dryerList's node-collection (since the code you posted contained some simple errors that are fixed in this jsfiddle, *excluding* the things mentioned in update 1, since you commented that this is not the problem) ?

May I ask (since you start at document.ready), why do you (still) check if dryerList already exists?
May I ask if you could update that corrected fiddle with some demo-data for us to toy around with?

Comment: Well, it sort of seems like it should, but no- the node[0].id value is correct, as I have alerted it several times and it shows exactly the value that it should, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: then when does it drop the id? Maybe a jsfiddle would be helpful to track this one down.

Comment: That's a thought, but defining id as node[0].id shouldn't affect dryerList[i].id- the two should be completely separate.  If that were the case, dryerList[i].id would return the value of node[0].id, but as it sits I am getting back undefined.

Comment: Did you try my solution?     Lets say node[0].id gives the text-string 'foobar'. You then store this to local var id. Then you effectively call dryerList[i].foobar, which does not exist thus gives 'undefined'. Makes sense to me so far.. But I might be mistaking.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a shot- I hadn't thought of it in that way.

Comment: No such luck.  My other code actually uses the ID variable name in a similar manner without incident.

Comment: Gotcha, you closed your document.ready function before you got to jstree!!

Comment: @Crash added update 4, containing fiddle to valid js version of your code.

Comment: sorry- got a little busy with some other work.  I think that must have been just an issue with the way I copied the code over- according to my IDE, the brackets are correct.  Looking at the code above, I think the close-bracket you mentioned is closing the if statement that begins just after the document.ready statement

Comment: crap you are right, sorry, my bad. It was a result of trying to fix the undeclared value. Ok, update 5. Please confirm.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly certain it's right.  I added a declaration for the binNodes array (forgot to copy it over before) and some test-data (this is the actual data being returned from the API).  As for the errors above, I have now corrected them in my local code.  I am still getting the message about .jstree not being a function (I am guessing this is because the jstree file is not included, but I'm not sure where to include it from online (I use a local copy of the jquery.jstree.js file).  Also, there's a couple alerts- it is not setting the proper value in binNodes, but it's in dryerList.

Comment: As for your question about why I am checking to see if the array has been defined, this code is a .js file that is meant to be as modular as possible- it is included along with other files that sometimes use the same variable, usually with a global scope (they include the same data, so it seems unnecessary to make the same request multiple times).

Comment: Well as you have seen, I've kept the check in fiddle ver 3. But if you want it to be modular you REALLY need to ditch the global vars like i !!!! In JS FIDDLE add this [link to jquery.jstree.js](http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js) under 'add resources' in panel and post back the link/jsfiddle-version here.

Comment: Well, now I'm even more confused.  It seems to be working fine on here, but still not on my system.  I am currently analyzing the code to see what differences I can find, but here is the link to the current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhvbs/6/

Comment: I see your jsfiddle [version 4](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhvbs/4/) does NOT include all fixes of my [version 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhvbs/3/), the version you confirmed to represent your intended code!  Please upgrade/expand on version 3. Don't forget adding the external scripts under 'add resources'. Also, click js-lint button regularly while adding code to version 3. Version 4 is currently again riddled with errors. Please postback your updated fiddle.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, in my local code I changed the scope on those iterators, so they should be nice and contained now.

Comment: wow, we are getting version hell here.. local code different scope, v4 not based on v3, and you are at v6 all of a sudden hihi.

Comment: lol- I'm not entirely sure how I jumped versions so far.  I just made a few of the extra changes that I had made to my code and not yet included in the fiddle, and now it is at version 7.  Shouldn't be anything major, but a few things changed.

Comment: That is starting to look better (thank you for your quick response). Since you wrote it seems to be working fine on here but not your system, it might also be a good idea to include the changes (like the changed scope on your iterators) in the fiddle. I mean: so we can work on your actual code with the demo-data you nicely appended to the fiddle. Now we are on track!

Comment: For some reason, when I include the code `for(var key in dryerList[0]) { alert(key + '\n' + dryerList[0][key]); }`, it lists out the elements 'n', 'x', 'y', and 'url', all with appropriate values, but not 'id'.

Comment: I just finished comparing this code to my local code, and with the exception of a few `document.getElementById('binLister').innerHTML = content;` statements, they are identical.

Comment: And I was wrong- it's not working on the fiddle now either.  I ran into an issue with dryerList showing up as undefined.  I had to remove the keyword 'var' from the declaration within document.ready to make it work again.

Comment: I think we should move to [SO-chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15088/discussion-between-gitaarlab-and-crash) if you can reach this chatbox